# Understanding the WLOG in theorem 6.3.2 of Roman Vershynin's High-dimensional Probability

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I have been trying to see why we can assume without loss of generality in theorem 6.3.2 of Roman Vershynin's [High-dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) [PDF] that $K \geq 1$. However, I have been unsuccessful.

---

> [image]

Comment: By assumption, the $X_i$ have unit variance. What does that tell you about $\|X_i\|_{\psi_2}$?

Comment: Using (2.15) on page 28 we know $ \frac{1}{2^{1/2}C_i}  \leq \|X_i\|_{\Psi_2}$ for some $C_i>0$. However, if we try and scale X by the min value, we affect the matrix $B$ in the formula.

Comment: Please make an effort to write the author's name correctly. At some point in the future, someone may have a question on the same theorem. It's hard to find previous questions if people mistype the authors' names.

Comment: You don't need to scale. As long as you know that $\|X_i\|_{\psi_2}\geq c >0$, you can hide the remaining factor in the constant $C$ of the theorem statement.

Comment: @PhoemueX but then this C won't be absolute right? As it will depend on the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to assume anything; the assumptions already imply that $K \geq 1$.

To see this, let $X$ be an arbitrary real random variable with variance $1$. I claim that $\|X\|_{\psi_2} \geq 1$. By definition, we have
$$
\|X\|_{\psi_2} = \inf \{ t > 0 : \Bbb{E}[\exp(X^2/t^2)] \leq 2\} .
$$
Now, note for $x \geq 0$ that $\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n! \geq 1 + x$, and hence
$$
\Bbb{E} [\exp(X^2/t^2)]
\geq 1 + \Bbb{E}[X^2/t^2],
$$
so that if $\Bbb{E} [\exp(X^2/t^2)] \leq 2$, then $t^{-2} = t^{-2} \mathrm{Var}(X) \leq \Bbb{E}[X^2/t^2] \leq 1$, i.e., $t\geq 1$.

Therefore, $\|X\|_{\psi_2} \geq 1$.